# Are concurrent programs faster than sequential ones?

Tags: concurrency

Are they faster or do they just appear faster to the user?

I mean if you have 100 tasks that each take 10 seconds long and take a total time of 1,000 seconds to process sequentially, wouldn’t it take longer if we concurrently programmed the process? Because each task would still take 10 seconds but now we also added the time it takes to switch between threads. Hmmm

I probably am misunderstanding something and would like some help understanding this.

Comment: "It depends". It depends on what resource your tasks are bound by and how much of that resource is available. If your tasks are CPU-bound and you have multiple cores then a concurrent program can in fact finish much faster, as it can do more work at the same time. If it's CPU-bound and there's only one core available (without hyperthreading), then adding concurrency will most likely just slow things down.

Comment: Everything you wrote sounds valid to me. Of course there is no magic involved if you run tasks in parallel, so total execution time of all tasks will be the same (or even slightly higher due to the overhead), but since all modern systems have multiple CPU cores, why no utilize them, work in parallel (where it makes sense) and reduce waiting time for the user?

Comment: And obviously it only "appears to be faster" according to your definition because parallelizing something cannot save computation time after summing all the parallel computation times. But that is what matters, the "appearance" of being faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it depends what you mean by concurrent

If by concurrent you mean thread running one after the other on one core, but not exactly simultanously (and by that I mean one single action at a time, but you switch action between threads), then it highly depends on the task.

Take for instance a task that contacts an URL, wait for the response, and then prints the result on your screen.

If you do it sequentially, you will contact the URL, wait, print the result, contact another URL, wait...

Now if you do it on a single core with multiple thread, you can contact an URL, and while waiting contact another URL. Since you do other task while waiting for the response, you are actually gaining time.

I took the example of URL, but there is multiple use case.

Now, if you use single thread concurrency for simple arithmetics operation (like only addition), you'll probably end up with a slow down since thread don't help you and you get overhead of creating them.

Finally, if we talk about multi-core threading (parallelization), depending on the task you can gain quite a lot of speed (depending on multiple factor such as the task, how much of it can you actually parallelize, how much will remain sequential..).